# Caligraphy meaning

Tags: meaning, seal

I’m a french man who bought a nice chinese caligraphy years ago.
Unfortunately I’m not able to understand it and don’t even know which direction I should display

Can anyone help me?
What is the meaning? Who is the artist?

Thanks for your support
Nicolas
[image]

Comment: only 柳 and 道 are clearly readable

Comment: might be kanji, japanese related?

Comment: Thanks guys. So this is not chinese but japanese. @水巷孑蠻 what is "kanji"?

Comment: it means "Han characters". It is written in Japanese by using the same characters as in traditional Chinese. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji

Comment: And obviously, the orientation of the picture is right.